# Get progression file upload

Tags: node.js, file, request, http-post, multipartform-data

I try to get the progression of my file uploading in node Js ... I use the form-data library integrated on request library ...

Is there any way to get my progression ?

```
var torrentStream = require('torrent-stream');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var request
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var zipFolder = require('zip-folder');
var magnet = require('magnet-uri')
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');


var formData = {
  files : fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/archive.zip')
};

request.post({url:'http://request.url', formData: formData}, 
function(err, httpResponse, body) {
 if (err) {
   return console.error('upload failed:', err);
 }
 console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

Comment: FYI, if you're only uploading a single file "archive.zip" then there's no reason to send it as multipart/form-data. Just set the request's `data` option to the readStream and set the request's `Content-Type` header to `application/zip`.